# C++ Decimal to hex string

Tags: c++

I have hexdecimal string like this,

```
   stringstream ss;
   ss<< hex << mynumber; 
   string res ( ss.str() );
  //res = 7c863231
  //First must be reverse string
```

So  I want this output,

```
  "\x31\x32\x86\x7c"
```

If I try combine strings like  "\x" + mystring doesnt work.So I have to directly convert .. Basically just trying to combine  hexdecimal bytes.

```
 string hex =  "\xbla\xbla\xbla";
 hex += "\\x" + HEXNUMBER; <-- this doesnt work.
 hex += "\xFF" <-- working ..
```

So as you can see I must convert direct addressing not ındirect addressing ..

Comment: If only we knew what `HEXNUMBER` actually *is*.... And you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: So I want this output,
  "\x31\x32\x86\x7c" Did you miss this line ? ..

Comment: I suspect you are looking for `string res((char*)&number, (char*)&number + sizeof(number));`